# Cannot install public python package, "error code 128 in none"

Tags: python-3.x, git, pycharm

I am trying to install a package from this repository :
https://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet

But i keep getting the error code 128. Yesterday it was a different error saying that git wasn't installed in PATH, apparently this one is fixed, not sure if that helps.

Tried enabling the port 22, reinstalling git etc, no luck.

```py
pip install git+git://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git
```

Comment: try pip install git+https://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, the message i am getting is : Invalid requirement: 'git+github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git'

Comment: The comment does not allow me to typwe https, replace git+git with git+https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was fixed by installing NI-Visa, and updating pyvisa directly from the master, thank you for your help!

http://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/drivers/download.ni-visa.html

Answer (score 2):

You can Try :

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git
```

or you clone the repo and install the package:

```
git clone https://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git
```

And then just run the setup.py file inside the directory:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: I should mention that i am on windows.
pip install git+https://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git gives me the usual 128 error.
git clone https://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git gives me a different one though, "  Could not resolve proxy: proxy.server.com ".

Comment: I can successfully install it using pip install git+https://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git

Comment: What does you C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\.gitconfig file look like update it in the question please

Comment: Apparently the problem was fixed by installing NI-Visa, and updating pyvisa directly from the master, thank you for your help!